# how to get max(date) from given set of data grouped by some fields using pyspark? Need to print all the records with this condition in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I need all the records which have `recent_run_date` grouped by `userid` and `memberid`. I need to print all the rows of this condition in pyspark.

```
date         | userId | memberId | value   
2016-04-06   | 1234   | 111      | 1
2016-04-06   | 1234   | 222      | 5
2016-04-06   | 1234   | 111      | 8
2016-04-06   | 1234   | 222      | 9
2016-04-05   | 4567   | 111      | 1
2016-04-06   | 4567   | 222      | 5
2016-04-06   | 4567   | 111      | 8
2016-04-06   | 4567   | 222      | 9
```

expected output

```
userId | memberId | datetime   | value
1234   |  111     | 2016-04-06 |  8
1234   |  222     | 2016-04-06 |  8
4567   |  111     | 2016-04-06 |  8
4567   |  222     | 2016-04-06 |  9
```

Comment: data = df.groupBy(['','']).agg(max_("date"))

Comment: I 'm using this but it is getting only particular column records. I need all the records with the max date grouped by user id and member id in pyspark.

Comment: Are you sure the second row of your expected output is 8? Max value for that userId and memberId is 9

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple [`groupby`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) with [`max`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.max) aggregation function

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy('userId', 'memberId').agg(F.max('date'), F.max('value')).show()

+------+--------+----------+----------+
|userId|memberId| max(date)|max(value)|
+------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1234|     222|2016-04-06|         9|
|  1234|     111|2016-04-06|         8|
|  4567|     222|2016-04-06|         9|
|  4567|     111|2016-04-06|         8|
+------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: But I also have some other columns like country , time, department. So based on this condition I need to print the total row(record) which satisfies this max date condition.

Comment: In this case I'm able to fetch only user, member id, date and value but not the whole row(record) and the remaining columns